# Object reference not set to an instance of an object (null DataSet??)

Tags: c#, tableadapter

I am trying to open a form by passing a value to its tableadapter.  In the code below Acct has a value but the error is on waterDataSet.AR.  Apparently it is null.  How can a dataset be null?  How would I go about getting around this error thanks!  Note that I use the commented out code in other places with no problems!

```
        public void LoadWaterAcct(String Acct, String tableName)
    {
        //demTableAdapter1.FillByStreet(waterDataSet.DEM, Num, Dir, Street);
       arTableAdapter1.FillByWaterAcct(waterDataSet.AR, Acct);

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `DataSet` is a reference type, it would be `null` if you haven't instantiated it, or if it has been garbage collected.

Comment: How can a dataset be null? The same way any other variable can. Is waterDataSet a global variable or something? Show the code where it is set.

Comment: To your second point, it won't be garbage collected if he has a reference to it.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - I assume that is pointed at me. You're right but a general question like *how can this be null* shows little understanding of how variables work so I figured I would include it in case the OP experiences it in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can a dataset be null?

`DataSet` is a reference type, so a variable of type `DataSet` is null until you assign a `DataSet` instance to it...

Comment: Are you saying that I need to write something like waterDataSet set = new waterDataSet("AR");  The reason this confuses me is because I didn't have to do this with the waterDataSet.DEM table??

Comment: @korrowan, if it works with waterDataSet.DEM, then it's not waterDataSet that is null... I suspect it's actually arTableAdapter1

Comment: it is indeed the tableadapter!  How do I fix the issue?

Comment: @korrowan, you initialize it... something like `arTableAdapter1 = new ArTableAdapter();` (check how it's done for demTableAdapter1)

Comment: BTW, you should *really* read a book about C#... your question shows that you lack understanding of some fundamental concepts, and you won't be able to go very far until you understand those concepts.

Comment: I have a book on C# but I don't have time to read it to be honest.  The issue for me is more often than not it is automatically created.  When its not it throws me off.  I just created the form and then the dataset and adapters and it did it all automatically. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @korrowan, don't rely on the tools too much... it helps you by generating some of the code, but you need to be able to understand this code and fix it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create  the `FillByWaterAcct` query? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kda44dwy.aspx